# IE6 reporting invalid argument when injecting PNG fix into head of document with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6, invalid-argument

Am having problems with the following code reporting an 'invalid argument' in IE6.

```
function LoadScriptsAndExecute(url) {
    this.url = url;
    this.loadScript = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.url,
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'script',
            success: function(){
                //alert(this.url);
            },
            error: function(){
                //alert('error');
            }
        }); 
        return true;                    
    }
}

// IE6 fixes | Semi-transparent PNG
if (icisSite.isIE(6, 'lte') == true) {

    var pngFix = new LoadScriptsAndExecute("/Global/ICIS/Scripts/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js");
    var pngList = new LoadScriptsAndExecute("/Global/ICIS/Scripts/DD_PNG_listing.js");
    pngFix.loadScript();    
    pngList.loadScript();       
}
```

Am pretty sure that i won't be able to get to the bottom of this as it is reporting an invalid argument on a line that does not exist.  All quite frustrating.

Comment: Have you commented out lines and see which one breaks the code? If it is the ajax calls, than look at the response with Fiddler and see what is being returned.

Comment: I have changed the implementation and just added the PNG fix scripts to the page prior to the closing body element.  The issue appears to be in the DD_belatedPNG_0.08-min.js file.  Debugging throws the invalid argument here:

Comment: /**
 * @param {String} selector - REQUIRED - a CSS selector, such as '#doc .container'
 **/
 fix: function (selector) {
  if (this.screenStyleSheet) {
   var selectors, i;
   selectors = selector.split(','); /* multiple selectors supported, no need for multiple calls to this anymore */
   for (i=0; i<selectors.length; i++) {
   
    alert(selectors + ',' + this);
    
    this.screenStyleSheet.addRule(selectors[i], 'behavior:expression(DD_belatedPNG.fixPng(this))'); /* seems to execute the function without adding it to the stylesheet - interesting... */
   
   }
  }
 },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided that due to the constraints of the framework not to bother with this implementation and let IE6 displays semi-transparent PNG as they are.